# C# how to return only one value from the list into a ComBox? Instead of all

Tags: c#

I am aiming to return a single value of `CustomerName` into a ComboBox.

This is how I get the data from the database:

```
public class DataAccess
{
    public List<ComplaintModel> FindOrderNumber(string orderNumber)
    {
        using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString.MJMconnString))
        {
            var output = conn.Query<ComplaintModel>($@"
                    SELECT 
                    TRIM(p.description) as Product,
                    c.name AS CustomerName,
                    FROM SalesOrder so JOIN SalesOrderLine sol ON
                    so.id = sol.salesOrderID JOIN Customer c ON
                    so.customerID = c.id JOIN Product p ON
                    sol.productID = p.id WHERE so.number = '{orderNumber}'").ToList();
            return output;
        }
    }
}
```

This would be the output (Used Excel to show you a rough idea):

[image]

So the ComboBoxes would look like this:

[image]

[image]

**Quick conclusion**

The customer name will always be the same for specific `OrderNumber` but products vary.

**Form**

Within my form I load the `Product` and `Customer` combo-box. (**Note:** I know you may be thinking to use a TextBox instead of a ComboBox for `Customer`, it just needs to be).

```
List<ComplaintModel> OrderNumber = new List<ComplaintModel>();

public void searchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    clearBindings();

    DataAccess db = new DataAccess();
     
    // Search Order Number that is specified in a text box
    OrderNumber = db.FindOrderNumber(orderNumber.Text);
  
    // List all products
    product.DataSource = OrderNumber;
    product.DisplayMember = "Product";

    // Show customer name - but as [0] instead of all.
    customer_name.DataSource = OrderNumber;
    customer_name.DisplayMember = "CustomerName";
    

}
```

**Desired output of combobox**

[image]

**This is my model**

```
public class ComplaintModel
{
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string Product { get; set; }
}
```

**Question**

How do I retrieve just a single value of `CustomerName` into the ComboBox?

Comment: If you have only one value, combo box isn't the most adapted control. You can display the customer's name in a label. For you question,  you can add only one element in the data source, like `customer_name.DataSource = new [] { OrderNumber[0] };`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create:
Customer class,
Order class.

Then You need to Create two lists for two comboboxes:
`List<Customer> customers` for customer combobox
`List<Order> orders` for orders combobox to show orders for selected customer (on combobox change event).

```
public class Customer
{
public string Id {get;set;}
public string Name {get;set;}
public List<Order> Orders {get;set;}
}

public class Order
{
public string Id {get;set;}
public string Name {get;set;}
public int CustomerId {get;set;}
}
```